# How do you send a RESTLET POST request without the optional parameter "; CHARSET=UTF-8" in the HTTP header?

Tags: utf-8, soapui, soap-client, restlet

How do you send a RESTLET POST request **without** the optional parameter "; CHARSET=UTF-8" in the HTTP header?

When I use WGET in UNIX to try this proof of concept for my service, I can specify the optional Content-type: ... in the HTTP header like this:

## Specifying the encoding as UTF-8:

```
wget --header="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"  --post-file=input_file.xml https://localhost/myservice
```

## Omitting the encoding:

```
wget --header="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  --post-file=input_file.xml https://localhost/myservice
```

When I do something like this in RESTLET

```
Form form = new Form();

String accessToken = "Moroni123";

form.set("access_token", accessToken);
```

If I do this to see the representation:

```
Representation rep = form.getWebRepresentation();
```

I see this using the rep.toString() method:

```
[application/x-www-form-urlencoded,UTF-8]
```

Is there a way I can get it to look like this?  **SoapUI** sends it without "UTF-8", how can I do this in RESTLET?

```
[application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
```

Comment: Can you give me the version of Restlet you use? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this hint corresponds to the character set within the Restlet representation. You can simply set it to `null` with the method `setCharacterSet` on the representation and you won't have anymore the UTF-8 in the header `Content-Type`. The following code describes this:

```
Form form = new Form();
String accessToken = "Moroni123";
form.set("access_token", accessToken);

Representation repr = form.getWebRepresentation();
MediaType mediaType = repr.getMediaType();
// corresponds to application/x-www-form-urlencoded
CharacterSet characterSet = repr.getCharacterSet();
// corresponds to UTF-8

rep.setCharacterSet(null);

ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://...");
cr.post(repr);
```

We will have the following request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Date: Thu, 19 Feb 2015 15:58:06 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Restlet-Framework/2.3.0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Host: 127.0.0.1:8181
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 22

access_token=Moroni123
```

Without this, the content of the header `Content-type` is:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

Hope it helps,
Thierry